# How can I split a string and then push something into the resulting array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this string:

```
var fruits = "banana,apple";
```

And I'm trying to add fruits to it by converting it to an array and then pushing the new fruit like this:

```
var newFruit = "orange";
fruits
  .split(",")
  .push(newFruit);
```

But this doesn't work because `fruits.split(",")` doesn't seem to return a "normal" array, i.e I can't perform `push()` on it.

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: Try `concat` instead of `push`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`split` does return a normal array. You are successfully calling `push` on it.

The problem is that you are then discarding the array so you can't do anything further with it.

Since `push` doesn't return the array itself, you have no way of using the array for anything further after calling `push` on it.

`concat` returns a new array that contains the additional values, but you would still have to do something with the array afterwards.

```js
var fruits = "banana,apple";
var newFruit = "orange";
var myArray = fruits
  .split(",")
  .concat(newFruit);
console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype.push` returns the new length of the array:

> **Return value:**
>
> The new length property of the object upon which the method was
>   called.
>
> [MDN Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#Return_value)

Also, you're not storing your new value. If you want to use push, here's how you'd do it:

```js
var fruits = "apple,banana";
var newFruits = fruits.split(","); // Store the new array
newFruits.push("orange"); // Add the new item

console.log(newFruits);
```

If you want to do it in one line, you can use `concat`:

```js
var fruits = "apple,banana";
var newFruits = fruits
      .split(",")         // Convert string to array
      .concat("orange");  // Create a new array joined with value

console.log(newFruits);
```

Answer (score 0):

push returns the new length of the array, because you are not saving it then you cant see the new array(after push)
try doing it in two lines:

```
newFruits = fruits.split(",");
newFruits.push(newFruit);
```